# Dynamic pivot using multiple columns where derived value may appear more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to figure out a way to dynamically pivot a results set based on the values heled within two columns.

I have a very basic query that returns information about the events associated with a particular job.

```
SELECT num, dat, [jobevtcls-cde] ,cde
FROM jobevt
WHERE   (num = 3177564)
ORDER BY cde
```

The results of this query are as follows:

```
+=========+============+===============+=====+
|   num   |    dat     | jobevtcls-cde | cde |
+=========+============+===============+=====+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  10 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  40 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  40 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  40 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  42 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  60 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  60 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           |  89 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           | 100 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           | 115 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | GEN           | 120 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-03-01 | GEN           | 120 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-26 | GEN           | 160 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           | 198 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | GEN           | 210 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-26 | GEN           | 220 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | GEN           | 310 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-26 | GEN           | 310 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
| 3177564 | 2021-02-24 | SYS           | 422 |
+---------+------------+---------------+-----+
```

I would like to pivot this data to show the cde + [jobevtcls-cde] as column headers with MAX(dat) as the row values.

The following code first of all complains about there not being a name for column four in D so I'm struggling to figure that one out.  The other thing SQL is complaining about are the multiple instances of the same code e.g. SYS40.

```
DECLARE @JobEventKey NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @JobEventKey += QUOTENAME([jobevtcls-cde] + CAST(cde AS VARCHAR(10))) + ','
FROM jobevt

WHERE jobevt.num = '3177564'

SET @JobEventKey = LEFT(@JobEventKey, LEN(@JobEventKey) -1)

SET @SQL = 

'SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
         num
        ,dat
        ,cde
        ,[jobevtcls-cde] + CAST(cde AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM
        jobevt
    WHERE
        (num = 3177564)
) AS D

PIVOT (
    MAX(dat)
    FOR cde IN (' + @JobEventKey +
    ')
) AS P'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

I'm fairly new to this kind of thing so any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why the "fairly new" people always tend to start with the more complex stuff like dynamic SQL? Anyway, your solution is close to working and the mistakes are easy enough to fix.

General guideline for dynamic SQL: build the solution in steps and print the constructed query (part) for validation during its construction. This allows you to execute the constructed query as well to validate the result.

**Errors**

> No column name was specified for column 4 of 'D'.

Your subquery `D` within the dynamic SQL query is missing a column name or alias. Add an alias with `as`.

> The column 'SYS40' was specified multiple times for 'P'.

The way you build up the value for `@JobEventKey` will produce a string like `[SYS10], [SYS40], [SYS40], ...`. The `pivot` column list from your pivoting result `P` expects *unique* column names. Add a `group by` to avoid duplicates.

```
DECLARE @JobEventKey NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @JobEventKey += QUOTENAME(cls + CAST(cde AS VARCHAR(10))) + ','
FROM jobevt

WHERE jobevt.num = '3177564'
--> num=3177564 contains multiple rows for "[SYS40]"
--> the contatenations contains duplicates!

SET @JobEventKey = LEFT(@JobEventKey, LEN(@JobEventKey) -1)

SET @SQL = 

'SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
         num
        ,dat
        ,cde
        ,cls + CAST(cde AS VARCHAR(10)) --> 4th column missing a name / alias!
    FROM
        jobevt
    WHERE
        (num = 3177564)
) AS D

PIVOT (
    MAX(dat)
    FOR cde IN (' + @JobEventKey +
    ')
) AS P'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Improved version**

Minor tweaks:

- Replaced `nvarchar(max)` with something more reasonable (depends on your data).
- Use table aliases where possible.
- Do not place quotes around integer values (for integer type columns).
- Add `order by` for sorted columns in after pivoting.

Final, working query:

```
DECLARE @JobEventKey NVARCHAR(1000) = '';

SELECT @JobEventKey += QUOTENAME(je.cls + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), je.cde)) + ','
FROM jobevt je
WHERE je.num = 3177564
group by QUOTENAME(je.cls + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), je.cde))
order by QUOTENAME(je.cls + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), je.cde));

SET @JobEventKey = LEFT(@JobEventKey, LEN(@JobEventKey)-1);

-- validate keys
select @JobEventKey;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000) = 
'SELECT P.*
 FROM ( SELECT je.num
              ,je.dat
              ,je.cls + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), cde) as clscde
        FROM jobevt je
        WHERE je.num = 3177564 ) AS d
 PIVOT (MAX(d.dat) FOR d.clscde IN (' + @JobEventKey + ')) AS P'

-- validate sql
select @sql;

-- execute
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

**Result**

Data used to replicate:

```
create table jobevt
(
  num int,
  dat date,
  cls nvarchar(3),
  cde int
);


insert into jobevt (num, dat, cls, cde) values
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  10),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  40),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  40),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  40),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  42),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  60),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  60),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS',  89),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS', 100),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS', 115),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'GEN', 120),
(3177564, '2021-03-01', 'GEN', 120),
(3177564, '2021-02-26', 'GEN', 160),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS', 198),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'GEN', 210),
(3177564, '2021-02-26', 'GEN', 220),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'GEN', 310),
(3177564, '2021-02-26', 'GEN', 310),
(3177564, '2021-02-24', 'SYS', 422);
```

Result:

```
num      GEN120      GEN160      GEN210      GEN220      GEN310      SYS10       SYS100      SYS115      SYS198      SYS40       SYS42       SYS422      SYS60       SYS89
-------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
3177564  2021-03-01  2021-02-26  2021-02-24  2021-02-26  2021-02-26  2021-02-24  2021-02-24  2021-02-24  2021-02-24  2021-02-24  2021-02-24  2021-02-24  2021-02-24  2021-02-24
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc1104aedda2ee4b8975098a94bd0c40) to see things in action.

Comment: You get an upvote just for that first paragraph. By the way, scalar variable aggregation is non-deterministic and pretty dangerous, you are much better off using `string_agg` or `for xml path`